# Word with separate translations in another language

Tags: terminology, lexical-semantics

Is there a name for the linguistic phenomenon of a word in language or dialect *X* with two or multiple meanings that have individual translations in language or dialect *Y*? For example, *escada* in Portuguese may refer to a *ladder* or *stairs*.

I know this is very common, but I'm wondering if there's a technical term for it, especially when it involves common nouns.

Comment: I don't know of a name for it, probably because it's so common—it'll be hard to find nouns that *don't* have this property. But it's hard to prove a negative, so this will remain a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: Not just nouns. In German _bekommen_ means 'receive', not 'become'; however, English _get_ can mean both 'receive' and 'become' -- _He got new orders; He got tired_.

Comment: Are you asking for a one(morpheme)-to-many(meanings) inside a language or a one(morpheme)-to-many(morpheme) between two varieties ? If it is the former, so you can speak of polysemy or polyreferentiality. If it is the latter, I don't know.

Comment: Translation ambiguity?